# .htaccess rule for locking down a specific page on my website is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, ip, restriction

I have an htaccess file with a rule in it to lock down a certain page on my site(example.com/logos). I want the page to only be seen if the person has an address of 43.xxx.xxx.xx
However it is not working. The first 3 lines is existing code that was already in the htaccess file.

My code, written in the htaccess file, and located in the 'logos' folder is below:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule  ^$    /content/content.php?PgName=logos [L]

RewriteRule ^content/([0-9|a-z|A-Z|_|\-]+)$ /content/content.php?PgName=$1 [L,NS]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^43\.xxx\.xxx\.xx
RewriteRule ^logos/([0-9]+) - [F,L]

Options -Indexes 
IndexIgnore */*
```

Comment: "not working" means that logos are always blocked or that logos are never blocked?

Comment: My apologies. It means that they are never blocked